# as you did/ as did you

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

> 1- I am saying that alcohol made you more susceptible to infection,
>   ***as did AZT***. (AZT is an antiretroviral  drug.) (Original, from a dialogue in a movie)
>
> 2- I am saying that alcohol made you more susceptible to infection,
>   ***as AZT did***.
>
> ---
>
> 3- No one understood the gift of life ***as you did***. ([Source](https://archive.nytimes.com/query.nytimes.com/gst/fullpage-9506E5D9123AF937A25750C0A96E9C8B63.html))
>
> 4- No one understood the gift of life, ***as did you***.

I don't understand when to invert the subject- verb order. Can I use the sentence 2 instead of 1? or 4 instead of 3? Is there a difference in meaning between and 1  and 2 or 3 and 4?

Answer (score 1):

Including initial *I am saying that* makes absolutely no difference to the syntax of the statement that follows. And *made you more susceptible to infection* is a pretty long verb phrase, so let's consider a simple one-word Present Tense verb (which again makes no difference to the syntax)...

> 1: *Alcohol evaporates, as does water*
>    2: *Alcohol evaporates, as water does*

In principle both the above are syntactically valid and mean the same - but version #1 is "marked" (it's an "unusual" form today, because in modern English the subject noun usually comes *before* the verb).

But *in practice*, this particularly subject/verb reversal has been retained as something of a "frozen form", so my example #1 is actually *more* common than #2. Note that this usage only applies after ***as*** - NOT after the near-equivalent ***like***...

> 3: *Alcohol evaporates, like does water*  <~~~ IDIOMATICALLY UNACCEPTABLE!
>    4: *Alcohol evaporates, like water does*
>    5: *Alcohol evaporates, like water*

Note example #5, showing that we can discard the auxiliary / helper verb ***does***. Also note these two *slightly* different interpretations that could apply to all my examples (except #3, which is simply invalid)...

> a:) *Alcohol evaporates. Water also evaporates*
>    b:) *Alcohol evaporates. Water evaporates **in the same way** that alcohol evaporates*

Since there's only really one way that liquids can evaporate, that's not a very meaningful distinction. But consider a slightly different context...

> 6: *I eat fish, as do the Japanese*
>    7: *I eat fish, as the Japanese do*
>    8: *I eat fish, like the Japanese do*
>    9: *I eat fish, like the Japanese*

Some native speakers would say that #6 is more likely to simply mean *I eat fish. The Japanese also eat fish*, whereas the others carry stronger implications that the ***way*** I eat fish (raw, using chopsticks) is similar to the way (stereotypical) Japanese do.

Some native speakers will also say it makes a difference whether I include a comma (pause, in speech) before ***as***. But even if that's true, it doesn't invalidate the points I'm making here.

---

TL;DR: The construction *[Subject1] [Verb] **as does** [Subject2]* inverts the normal subject+_verb sequence for ***Subject2*** and ***does***. This *was* common in English back in Shakespeare's time, but it only survives today in certain specific contexts. Using it today is thus slightly "formal, literary". Consider...

> 10: I watch TV, as do you
>    11: I watch TV, as you do
>    12: I watch TV, like you [do]

All these examples mean (approximately) the same thing. But they're in decreasing order of formality.

Comment: Thank you so much. What about the situations where "as is/are + noun/adjective is used? For example: "But she’s also finding that the acting industry she left behind is very different now. ***As is*** New York City." Can I rewrite this sentence as in "...very different now ***as New York City is***" ?

Comment: *Syntactically*, there's no problem with *...very different now **as** New York City **is***. But as I pointed out above, for this *exact* construction, the subject/verb reversal is still much more common. But these are quite fine details about "stylistic choices". Note that in your latest example above, I'd probably use ***So** is NYC* if I was going to write it as a separate sentence, but ***, as is NYC*** if I was just continuing the previous sentence. And for added emphasis, I'd use *As is NYC **itself***, but I wouldn't use ***itself*** with standard word order, or with ***so***.